# Jquery automatically form submit, but returns nothing

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using Keith Jquery Countdown 1.5.8 for doing the countdown and the ticking time is working perfectly for every user. i have 2 forms in a single php file (let's say multiform.php) but the form submits nothing when the countdown reaches zero.

Here is my jquery code  :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: <?php echo($usertime); ?>,
    onExpiry: function() {
        $('#quizform').submit();
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

and some of my multiform.php codes are :

```
<?php
    if($choice==1) {
?>
...
<form action="submit.php" method="post" name="quizform" id="quizform">
...
...
<input type="submit" name="save_1" value="Save" />
</form>

<?php
    } else {
?>
...
<form action="submit.php" method="post" name="quizform" id="quizform">
...
...
<input type="submit" name="save_2" value="Save" />
</form>
```

and submit.php consists of :

```
if(isset($_POST['save_1'])) {
    ...do part 1
}
else {
    ...do part 2
}
```

The form submits nothing, none of those text input values submitted to "submit.php". It returns blank.
Am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried adding `echo '<pre>';var_dump($_POST);echo '</pre>';die();` to the top of **submit.php**? This should give you a raw insight into what is actually being sent across.

Comment: it returns
array(5) {
  ["hal"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["idsoaltes"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["idsoal"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  ["pilihan2"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["pilihan1"]=>
  string(1) "2"
}

Comment: well, the form actually submits the text input value to submit.php, but why the values aren't updated into database. is it because of the values aren't passed into : if(isset($_POST['save_1'])) {

Comment: I really recommend not using the same ID for two elements .. How would you know which form was actually submitted.

Comment: ok, what should i suppose to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have the solution here - from memory, when you submit a form using Javascript, as opposed to clicking the "submit" button, the values held in the "submit" button are not carrier through.

Example:

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php">
  <input name="field1" value="One">
  <input name="field2" value="Two">
  <input type="submit name="save" value="Save">
</form>
```

When submitted via clicking on the "Save" button will return

```
$_POST = array( 'field1'=>'One' , 'field2'=>'Two' , 'save'=>'Save' );
```

If submitted via Javascript it will return

```
$_POST = array( 'field1'=>'One' , 'field2'=>'Two' );
```

To resolve this, add a hidden field containing the value you want transmitted, regardless of the method

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="formID' value="TheFirstForm">
  <input name="field1" value="One">
  <input name="field2" value="Two">
  <input type="submit name="save" value="Save">
</form>
```

Which will return, via a click of the button

```
$_POST = array( 'formID'=>'TheFirstForm' ,'field1'=>'One' , 'field2'=>'Two' , 'save'=>'Save' );
```

And with a Javascript submission

```
$_POST = array( 'formID'=>'TheFirstForm' ,'field1'=>'One' , 'field2'=>'Two' );
```

Comment: ok, i'll try it.
I'll post the updated result...
Thanks for pointing it out Lucanos

Comment: Apparently submitting form via button click is different from submitting form on javascript. Thank you Lucanos. It works well now :)